# What kind of sound input socket is this?

Tags: electrical, socket, audio

I have this surround sound system at home that is very old and have these strange sound input sockets that I have never seen before. Does anyone know what kind of input socket this is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS778US778&biw=1474&bih=772&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=aTxbW7KRHZHijwTphZ-ABg&q=kroser+%22master+sound+control%22&oq=kroser+%22master+sound+control%22&gs_l=img.3..35i39k1l2.372125.375031.0.375435.4.4.0.0.0.0.119.455.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.3.344....0.kR8H1O31pQk#imgrc=tKFbfEf9zwxmLM:)

Comment: That reminds me of an old [DIN Loudspeaker Connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Loudspeaker_connector), except that your one has 2 round pins - one on each side, in addition to the flat one.

Comment: I would think that those are not the actual inputs, rather the sound level adjustments using a special square tool to prevent unauthorized tampering.    Actua inputs are probably in back of under a removable panel

Comment: But if you look at the sockets they seem to have a copper connector or something similar.

Comment: could be a custom connector, i've never seen one like that before, and i've seen a lot of audio connectors...

Comment: I couldn't even find a reference to the Kroser brand name.

Comment: @fixer1234 Funny, the first Google Search result for me was their website: http://www.kroser-electronica.com/marcomenu.html - the logo has been modernized a bit, but it's clearly the same company based on the product catalog - some of the product pictures still have the old logo.

Comment: Of course, the website is also totally broken...

Comment: @MosheKatz, the Google force is strong in you.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 But of course the website has no information, and I just finished scouring the Wayback Machine for older versions with no results.

Comment: Note: It is **not** the same as Bang & Olufsen's 3-pin DIN cable modification. That cable has the extra pin off-center in order to ensure that it gets inserted correctly.

Comment: The 2007 Kroser Catalog is finally available:
http://www.kroser-electronica.com/descargas/catalogo2007.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but the connector is called “dot dash” if you literally translate it from Portuguese. I have searched the web for the English name of it, but I was unsuccessful.

These connectors must be at least 20 years old... guess the best solution is to update the entire sound system

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer; if you think it's the best one for your question, click the checkmark to mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be the 220V inputs (source feeds - Fuente alimentación) for each device; (L and R) as each input looks like it has two connection points. It has a custom connector that I cannot identify. If you can read spanish the manual more information is here: www.kroser-electronica.com/descargas/catalogo2007.pdf

Comment: 220V?? Most audio inputs are 1V or less, are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the 2-pin DIN connector like others said, and you can insert it with the small pin to the right or left. Or is some custom connector, to find out for sure you would have to open the panel up to look at the pins.

I also found the same hotel sound control thing on another website where someone is looking for a technician to fix it. And his version got 5-pin DIN connectors link: [Other website with 5-pin version](http://tumanitas.com/trabajos/cambiar-placa-de-casa-con-hilo-musical)

Some more info and pinout of DIN connectors: [Here](https://www.electronics2000.co.uk/pin-out/dincon.php)

The fastest way to find out what sockets they are, is to open it up and look how many connectors come out from the socket.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you may want to [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Loudspeaker_connector) specifically mentions a version of the two pin female din where "Most common is a three-hole female connector with one circular hole on either side of the spade hole, one of them with an aux contact and one without, which provides the option to leave the internal speaker connected by inserting the plug twisted by 180°"

I can't find that specific looking DIN anywhere though.